# Complex differentiability at one point and loop integral around it

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ be differentiable real functions with continuous partial derivatives in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. Prove that $f = u+ iv$ is
complex differentiable at $z_0$ if and only if
                $$\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\oint_{C(z_0,r)}f(z)dz=0$$

Where  $C(z_0, r)$ is the circle of radius r centered at $z_0$. 
I think this maybe related to Cauchy formula but the condition seems to point toward Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: Note that it doesn't say that $f$ is necessarily holomorphic at $z_0$, only that it is complex differentiable at $z_0$. The former would imply complex differentiable in some *neighbourhood* around $z_0$, which is *stronger*. This rules out the cauchy formula, I think, so you'll need to basically show that this limit only holds if the partial derivatives fulfill the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations at $z_0$.

Comment: I think i've figured it out, the main idea is to use Green's theorem to change the loop integral into Cauchy Riemann related expression. Then take the limit LOL

Answer (score 1):

We have
$f(z)dz=f(x+iy)d(x+iy)=(u+iv)(dx+idy)=udx+iudy+ivdx-vdy$
Thus we can write the contour integral as the line integral of a differential form

$$\displaystyle\oint_{C(z_0,r)}f(z)dz=\displaystyle\oint_{C(z_0,r)}udx-vdy+i\displaystyle\oint_{C(z_0,r)}vdx+udy$$

Since $u,v$ are both differentiable by assumption, we can apply Green's Theorem and get

$$\displaystyle\oint_{C(z_0,r)}f(z)dz=\displaystyle\iint_{D(z_0,r)}(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})dxdy+i\displaystyle\iint_{D(z_0,r)}(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})dxdy$$

Now apply mean value thm for double integral

$$\displaystyle\oint_{C(z_0,r)}f(z)dz=\pi r^2[-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(z_0+\rho e^{i\theta})-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(z_0+\rho e^{i\theta})]+i\pi r^2
[-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z_0+\rho' e^{i\theta'})-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(z_0+\rho' e^{i\theta'})]$$

for suitable $0<\rho,\rho'<r$ and $0<\theta,\theta'<2\pi$

As $r$ tends to $0^{+}$, $z_0+\rho e^{i\theta}$ and $z_0+\rho' e^{i\theta'}$ tend to $z_0$, uniformly w.r.t $\theta$ and $\theta'$.

Hence the RHS of last equation (divided by $\pi r^2$)goes to zero iff $u,v$ satisfy CR-equation in $z_0$, i.e iff $f$ is differentiable in the complex sense at $z_0$

Comment: There seems to be a sign error in the application of Green's theorem (namely the first double integral)

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is differentiable, we have
$$
f(z)=f(z_0)+f_x(z_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(z_0)(y-y_0)+o(z-z_0)\tag{1}
$$
and along $C(z_0,r)$,
$$
\mathrm{d}z=r(-\sin(\theta)+i\cos(\theta))\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{2}
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{\pi r^2}\oint_{C(z_0,r)}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac1{\pi r^2}\int_0^{2\pi}{\Large(}f(z_0)+f_x(z_0)r\cos(\theta)+f_y(z_0)r\sin(\theta)+o(r){\Large)}\,r(-\sin(\theta)+i\cos(\theta))\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=if_x(z_0)-f_y(z_0)+\frac1\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{o(r)}{r}(-\sin(\theta)+i\cos(\theta))\mathrm{d}\theta\\[6pt]
&\to if_x(z_0)-f_y(z_0)\\[6pt]
&=iu_x(z_0)-v_x(z_0)-u_y(z_0)-iv_y(z_0)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{r\to0}\frac1{\pi r^2}\oint_{C(z_0,r)}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z
=iu_x(z_0)-v_x(z_0)-u_y(z_0)-iv_y(z_0)\tag{4}
$$
Equation $(4)$ says that the condition given above
$$
\lim_{r\to0}\frac1{\pi r^2}\oint_{C(z_0,r)}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=0\tag{5}
$$
is precisely the Cauchy-Riemann conditions at $z_0$:
$$
\begin{align}
u_x(z_0)&=v_y(z_0)\\
u_y(z_0)&=-v_x(z_0)
\end{align}\tag{6}
$$